# Keep backward compatibility for Maven assembly plugin from 2.4 to 2.4.1

Tags: maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

The project has the following structure:

```
M
+---A
+---B
|   +---B1
|   +---B2
|
+---C
+---D
```

Every folder (M,A,B,B1,B2,C,D) contains a **pom.xml** file.

The pom.xml file from B1 contains the following lines:

```
<configuration>
    <filters>
        <filter>B/B1/PATH_TO_FILE_X</filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
```

Running

```
mvn clean install -Px -Dy -X
```

from the M folder:

- using assembly plugin **2.4**, everything works **fine**. It looks for `path\M\B\B1\PATH_FO_FILE_X` and it exists. (absolute path = project path + specified path)
- using assembly plugin **2.4.1** (or **2.5.3**), the **file** is **not found**. It looks for `path\M\B\B1\B\B1\PATH_TO_FILE_X` and there is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. (absolute path = submodule path + specified path)

I can manually change every path that cannot be resolved, but it's too risky because some paths can be resolved in a wrong way. If there is `B\B1\PATH_TO_ANOTHER_FILE_X` in `B\B1\` it could cause problems.

Is there a generic method to solve this problem (keeping backward compatibility from 2.4 to 2.4.1)?

**Details:**

- Maven 3.2.1
- Java 7
- Windows 7

---

**Update:**

It seems to be related to **maven-filtering 1.2** that was introduced in 2.4.1:

- http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Maven-Assembly-Plugin-Version-2-4-1-Released-td5801647.html
- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-686
- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED-161
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-301
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201211.mbox/%3C1791127681.01353276825400.JavaMail.Dennis@Dennis-Dator%3E

The following line from 2.4:

```
<mavenFilteringVersion>1.1</mavenFilteringVersion>
```

was replaced by

```
<mavenFilteringVersion>1.2</mavenFilteringVersion>
```

in 2.4.1.

Comment: First i would suggest to use the most up-to-date version 2.5.3 instead of older version and do a recheck. Apart from that can you create an example project which shows the behaviour. If you really find a problem please fill in a jira issue.

Comment: I updated my question. I mentioned 2.4 and 2.4.1 because between those versions there was a change. But 2.5 or 2.5.3 are also different regarding those "relative paths".

Comment: Can you create a full working example where this problem occurs? It would be helpfull if you create a jira issue for that http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I didn't start to create a simple example because I found some useful JIRAs that were already raised and it seems that the problem is related to maven-filtering 1.2 that is used by the assembly plugin.

Comment: Sorry but this does not help. All these jira's are solved. The information that there has been an update is alredy known (see version control). What we need an example which reproduces the behaviour. Creating a new issue in jira will help more. Nor have you posted a full pom file and no descriptor which is used.